# Rotating x labels on multi y-axis graph

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
...
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
...
new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
...
```

to define a graph with multiple y axes, as per [this demo sample](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html)

but my x-axis labels are dates and I would like to rotate them using

```
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

This though requires, iiuc, getting the Figure object, and I can't seem to find where host_subplot() makes that available to me.

## Update

I've found I can get the figure by calling

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[8,10])
```

before host_subplot.

But fig.autofmt_xdate() seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened is your `axes_class` becomes "[a custom (and very experimental) Axes class](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/toolkits/axisartist.html?highlight=set_ticklabel_direction#axisartist)" whose ticklabels cannot be processed by `fig.autofmt_xdate()`. In order to set ticklabels, you have to follow [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/tutorials/toolkits/axisartist.html?highlight=set_ticklabel_direction#rotation-and-alignment-of-ticklabels). As you can imagine, you have two options:

1. Use `axes_class=AA.Axes`: you will need to do 3 things to achieve the result of `fig.autofmt_xdate()`

   a. Rotate ticklabels by `host.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_rotation(30)`

   b. Set alignment by `host.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_ha("right")`

   c. Move x-axis label by `host.axis["bottom"].label.set_pad(30)`

   A complete example and its result:

   ```
   from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
   import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
   plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

   par1 = host.twinx()
   par2 = host.twinx()

   offset = 60
   new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
   par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                       axes=par2,
                                       offset=(offset, 0))

   par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)

   host.set_xlim(0, 2000000)
   host.set_ylim(0, 2)

   host.set_xlabel("Distance")
   host.set_ylabel("Density")
   par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
   par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

   p1, = host.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
   p2, = par1.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
   p3, = par2.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

   par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
   par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

   host.legend()

   host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
   par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
   par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

   host.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_rotation(30)
   host.axis["bottom"].major_ticklabels.set_ha("right")
   host.axis["bottom"].label.set_pad(30)

   plt.draw()
   plt.show()
   ```

[image]

2. Do not use `axes_class=AA.Axes` so that you can use `fig.autofmt_xdate()`: you will need to remove the `, axes_class=AA.Axes` part as well as the following 3 lines since they are `axisartist.Axes` specific.

   ```
   new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
   par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                       axes=par2,
                                       offset=(offset, 0))

   par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)
   ```

   However, your 3rd axis will overlap your 2nd axis. You need to use the following 2 lines to move it right:

   ```
   par2.spines["right"].set_position(('outward', offset))
   par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)
   ```

   You can use `fig.autofmt_xdate()` now. A complete example and its result:

   ```
   from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   host = host_subplot(111)
   plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

   par1 = host.twinx()
   par2 = host.twinx()

   offset = 60
   par2.spines["right"].set_position(('outward', offset))
   par2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

   host.set_xlim(0, 2000000)
   host.set_ylim(0, 2)

   host.set_xlabel("Distance")
   host.set_ylabel("Density")
   par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
   par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

   p1, = host.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
   p2, = par1.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
   p3, = par2.plot([0, 1000000, 2000000], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

   par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
   par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

   host.legend()

   host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())
   par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
   par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())

   plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

   plt.draw()
   plt.show()
   ```

[image]

Comment: One of the most comprehensive answers I've seen here in a long time: seriously above and beyond.  Many thanks!